# Solr error creating core: fieldType [x] not found in the schema

Tags: xml, solr, configuration, schema

I am trying to get a Solr core running with my own `schema.xml`, but Solr (version 5.2.1) keeps complaining about missing `fieldType` elements that aren't even in my `fields` definitions.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: fieldType 'booleans' not found in the schema
```

Whenever I add a 'missing' `fieldtype` another error pops up complaining about another `fieldType` missing, like `longs`, etc., until I've added them all and the schema is accepted without error.

Now how come I must provide these `fieldtype` elements when there is no use for them?

In `config.xml` I have:

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

Here's my `schema.xml`:

```
<schema name="collections" version="1.5">

<fields>
    <field name="id_object" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="id_organization" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="artist" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="searchname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="technique_group" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="technique" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="color_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="color" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="subject" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="height" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="width" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="depth" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="price_sale" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="price_rental" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="price_rental_with_savings" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="savings_portion" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="year" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="is_for_rent" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="is_for_sale" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="status" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="shipment" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="timestamp" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" />

    <!-- catch all field, must be multiValued if any of its source fields is -->
    <field name="quick_search" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <!-- mandatory -->
    <field name="_version_" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true" />

</fields>

<uniqueKey>id_object</uniqueKey>

<copyField source="id_object" dest="quick_search" />
<copyField source="title" dest="quick_search" />
<copyField source="artist" dest="quick_search" />
<copyField source="searchname" dest="quick_search" />
<copyField source="technique_group" dest="quick_search" />
<copyField source="technique" dest="quick_search" />
<copyField source="color_type" dest="quick_search" />
<copyField source="color" dest="quick_search" />
<copyField source="subject" dest="quick_search" />

<types>
    <fieldtype name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
    <fieldtype name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" />
    <fieldtype name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" />
    <fieldtype name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" />
    <fieldtype name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" />
    <fieldtype name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" />
    <fieldtype name="text" class="solr.TextField"/>
</types>

</schema>
```

There is not a single `multiValued` field in there. Nonetheless I tried explicitly setting `multiValued='false'` for each field individually, but to no avail. Even when I strip the entire schema down to just a handful of `String` fields it still generates that error.

I'm pretty confident my `schema.xml` is OK but perhaps some setting somewhere should tell Solr to take it easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
    <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
</lst>
```

over here you need to correct "booleans" to "boolean".

```
<lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
    <str name="fieldType">boolean</str>
</lst>
```

Then it will work..

Or

The alternate solution is to comment out the `<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema">` section in `solrconfig.xml`.

Comment: That looks like a far more elegant solution than just commenting the entire thing out. In order for this to work I had to use **ManagedIndexSchemaFactory** instead of **ClassicIndexSchemaFactory**, set `mutable=true` and use a name other than schema.xml

Comment: in `Solr 6.3.0` it also works. Needed section can be found in `solrconfig.xml`. By the way, I also needed to remove `s` from `tdates`, `tlongs` and from `tdoubles`. I took `solrconfig.xml` from `basic_configs`.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure whether it is the preferred way to go, but commenting out the `solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory` section in `config.xml` seems to solve the issue.

```
<!--
<processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
    <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tlongs</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Number</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tdoubles</str>
  </lst>
</processor>
-->
```

Comment: In my solr 5.2.1 instance I found this section in `solrconfig.xml`. Commenting it out worked for me, too. Thanks

Comment: Use default ckan schema, also for mer worked. Thanks!